# Automotive or solid state relay as main switch for 3D printer?

Tags: arduino, relay, safety, automotive, solid-state-relay

I have 47A 12V server power supply for my 3D printer project. The idea is to add a relay before printer hardware (RAMPS, Arduino Mega clone, steppers, bed heater etc). The normally open relay is then controlled by a separate Arduino Uno which monitors temperature sensors inside printer enclosure and sends constant signal if everything is ok.

For an automotive relay I would need to use an opto isolator to control a 12V line as Arduino Uno signal won't be enough to energize the relay. With SSR I guess could avoid that but is there any other benefit of using SSR instead of automotive relay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is related to the safety, then SSR is not a good choice, because in case of short circuit the SSR will melt down making a continous conduction, therfore you are not able to disconnect the load anymore.

Comment: This isn't a very good answer - why not? What are the disadvantages?

Comment: The SSR  will be less forgiving when it comes to surges than the mechanical relay. The SSR will waste more voltage and therefore make more heat .If the number of operations is not great then a mechanical relay is probably best.If you do go solid state you may have to back up with mechanical for safety / approval reasons anyway.